# Can not write to file, even though is_writable returns true

Tags: php, file-io, permissions, fopen

Anyone have any ideas on this? I check the file with `file_exists()` and `is_writable()`, both of which return true. I set the directory and file to `777` just to be safe as well, but **trying fwrite() or file_put_contents() both result in no change in the file**

Here is the relevant code:

```
$filePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . 'myfile.txt';
file_put_contents($filePath, "waffles are delicious");
```

Comment: Do they result in error messages?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no error messages :-/

Comment: What's the return value of `file_put_contents()`

Comment: works now. Honest to goodness, all I did was wrap a var_dump() around the file_put_contents call. Not sure what was going on

Comment: @JoeCortopassi that sounds like a output buffer issue then. Make sure the program wasn't getting terminated before the file was closed.

Comment: While developing it's recommended to have display_errors on and error_reporting on value -1 (show all possible errors). I suspect that they were not exactly set like this in your case.

Comment: @gphilip error_reporting is on as is display errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've checked the permissions of the file but also have a look at the ownership.

I've often seen issues where files are unpacked from archives with a uid/gid from the originating system. This is usually the case when you've uploaded and unpacked a zip or tar.gz installation archive of a framework, CMS or forum instead of waiting for all the files to be uploaded through FTP.

To change the file owner you'll need to do a `chown` command in the shell to change it to the username/group of your account. You will probably need to be root/su to do this.

```
chown -R username:groupname *
```

The `-R` makes it recursive an applies to all files in all subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the closing php tag to make sure this isn't a whitespace issue.